# Can't access "filter" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Somehow, I can't access my image tag's applied filter attributes. I have a page which sets filter attributes. i.e. set brightness to 200%, applied image filter brightness to 200%.

JavaScript code to read input / set filter value. In CSS:

```
img { filter: blur(var(--blur)) grayscale(var(--grayscale)) brightness(var(--brightness)) contrast(var(--contrast)) hue-rotate(var(--hue)) invert(var(--inv)) opacity(var(--opa)) saturate(var(--sat)) sepia(var(--sepia)); }
```

Everything works fine. The image changes as I input. But somehow, I can't read the style attributes at all.

```
console.log(document.querySelector("img").style.filter);
```

or `.style`

When I do this, it shows `null` (nothing)... There is only one img tag in html file (). I wonder why I can't read filter attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `style` property only shows inline styles in the HTML tag's `style` attribute, not CSS from any stylesheets or `<style>` tags.

In order to get the style given from a stylesheet, you have to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("img")).filter
```